# Como limpar buffer em menu numérico quando digitam-se strings?

Tags: c++

Como implementar um menu que leia valores numéricos e indique erro (mensagem na tela) quando recebe caracteres e strings? O código abaixo deu certo para caracteres individuais através do `if(std::cin >> opcao)`, mas para cadeias de caracteres ele armazena o buffer e substitui diversas vezes - dependendo do tamanho da cadeia.

**Código:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Elemento.h"

int main()
{
    int opcao;

    Elemento e = 0;

    Elemento::mostrarMenu();

    do{
        std::cout << "Opção: ";

        if(std::cin >> opcao){          

            switch(opcao){

                case 1:
                    Elemento::adicionar(e);
                    Elemento::listar();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Elemento::listar();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    std::cout << "Encerrando." << std::endl;
                    break;

                default:
                    std::cout << "Opção inválida." << std::endl;
                    break;      
            }// fim switch()

            std::cin.clear();
        }//fim if cin
        else{

            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::cout << "Digite um número válido" <<std::endl;
        }

      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore();
    }
    while(opcao != 3); // fim do - while()
}
```

**Comando de compilação:**

`clang++ -Wall -ansi -O main.cpp Elemento.cpp -o Elemento`

**Execução:**

`Menu:
1 - Adicionar.
2 - Mostrar.
3 - Sair.
    Opção: r
    Digite um número válido
    Opção: rafael
    Digite um número válido
    Opção: Digite um número válido
    Opção: Digite um número válido
    Opção: _`

Como fazer para exibir o aviso presente em `else` somente uma vez, mesmo que o usuário digite uma string?

Coloquei vários `cin.ignore` e `cin.clear` que melhoraram a situação, mas não resolveram. Qual a forma mais simples (e/ou eficiente) de lidar com essa situação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu caso é bem simples. Você so precisa ler o restante do string. Você pode usar o codigo seguinte no else.

```
else
    {
        //bad token
        cin.clear();
        string badToken;
        cin >> badToken;
        cerr << "Entrada invalidade encontrada: " << badToken << endl;
    }
```

Assim, quando o loop iniciar de novo o buffer vai estar vazio. Voce tb pode ler todos os caracteres com um cin.get() em um while, mas acho mais facíl ler tudo em um string de uma vezes.
E tb o cin.clear() não limpa o buffer ele so reseta o estado do cin para o padrão. Então pode remover o cin.clear() e o cin.ignore() depois do else.